# Skip multiple sheets in loop by the sheets codename

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that loops all the sheets in my workbook and need to skip some of the sheets that will be hidden in my workbook by their codename

This is the code im using.

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
For Each WS In Worksheets

'Skips sheets below
example Skip .sheetscodename, .sheetscodename2, and so on


'Insert code to be looped here
Set Rng = WS.Range("C7", WS.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp))
For Each cel In Rng
If cel.Value = "0" Then
cel.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next cel

'Next sheet
    Next WS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to create a string of all the names to be skipped, then use InStr():

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range, Rng As Range
Dim shts As String
shts = ("sheetscodename,sheetscodename2,...")
For Each WS In Worksheets

    If InStr(1, shts & ",", WS.CodeName & ",", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then


        'Insert code to be looped here
        Set Rng = WS.Range("C7", WS.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp))
        For Each cel In Rng
            If cel.Value = "0" Then
            cel.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        Next cel
    End If

'Next sheet
Next WS
```

Comment: i can't seem to get it to work with more than one sheet. 
`shts = ("BlankOptionSheet")` this works and skips the sheet
but when i try to add more sheet names to it it no longer works on any sheets 
`shts = ("BlankOptionSheet,BlankBidSheet")` when i do this it stops from working

Comment: @luke sorry had the criteria backwards.  See edit.  You may need to refresh the screen.  Remember to mark as correct if it works for you by clicking the check mark by the answer.